# Default value of Type in Generic classes in Typescript

Tags: javascript, generics, typescript, default-value

I need to set a default value of a variable based on its type in Typescript generic classes like below

```
  class MyClass<T>{
      myvariable: T // Here I want to set the value of this variable 
                    // with the default value of the type passed in 'T'
    }
```

For example if the T is number then the default value of the variable `myvariable` should be "0", similarly for string it should be empty string and so on..

Comment: You can't define it in the abstract class; the information of T is not available at runtime.

Comment: why..? if I have created an instance of this class like var obj = MyClass<string>()...at run time T will be string.

Answer (score 12):

You can't do that as the actual type which is `T` will only be known at runtime.

What you can do:

```
abstract class MyClass<T> {
    myvariable: T;

    constructor() {
        this.myvariable = this.getInitialValue();
    }

    protected abstract getInitialValue(): T;
}
```

Now you just extend this class, like so:

```
class MyStringClass extends MyClass<string> {
    protected getInitialValue(): string {
        return "init-value";
    }
}
```

---

#### Edit

What you're asking for can not be done because `T` only exists in the typescript realm, and it doesn't "survive" the compilation process.

For example, this:

```
class MyClass<T> {
    myvariable: T;

    constructor(value: T) {
        this.myvariable = value;
    }
}
```

Compiles into:

```
var MyClass = (function () {
    function MyClass(value) {
        this.myvariable = value;
    }
    return MyClass;
}());
```

As you can see, in the compiled version there's no `T`, so you can't use that information at runtime in order to generate a default value.

---

Another solution is to have a map of default values:

```
var defaultValues = {
    "string": "",
    "number": 0,
    "boolean": false
}

class MyClass<T> {
    myvariable: T;

    constructor(value: T) {
        this.myvariable = value;
    }
}

let a = new MyClass<string>(defaultValues.string);
let b = new MyClass<boolean>(defaultValues.boolean);
```

---

You can also use static factory methods:

```
class MyClass<T> {
    myvariable: T;

    constructor(value: T) {
        this.myvariable = value;
    }

    static stringInstance(): MyClass<string> {
        return new MyClass<string>("");
    }

    static numberInstance(): MyClass<number> {
        return new MyClass<number>(0);
    }

    static booleanInstance(): MyClass<boolean> {
        return new MyClass<boolean>(false);
    }
}

let a = MyClass.stringInstance();
let b = MyClass.booleanInstance();
```

Comment: exactly...that is what I'm asking is there any construct to which I pass T and it gives me the default value of T at run time.

Comment: No, there's no `T` in runtime so you can not use it.. I edited my answer with an example

Comment: Don't want to pass anything in the constructor..need something like this myvariable: T =defaultOF(T)...I know T is not there in the javascript after the code generation..

Comment: Well, we don't always get what we want...  You'll need to workaround the problem that javascript doesn't have the notion of types. If you don't want to pass a value to the ctor then use the first solution I gave in my answer and implement a class per type, or check the 3rd edit of my answer (static factory functions).

Answer (score 0):

`T` is lost at runtime, so you need to pass in the type like a value. And you can do that by passing the constructor.

When I have a similar need, I usually use an interface like this:

```
interface Type<T> {
     new() : T;
}
```

And create MyClass like so:

```
class MyClass<T>{
    myvariable: T;

    constructor(type: Type<T>) {

        this.myvariable = new type();
    }
}
```

Then I can use MyClass like so:

```
let myinstance = new MyClass(TheOtherType);
```

It works for classes, but not for built-ins like string and number.

`TheOtherType` is the constructor of a class such as:

```
class TheOtherType {
}
```

Comment: I don't want to pass anything through my constructor and then assign that value to the variable..what I need is there any construct which I can directly assign to my variable like this myvariable: T =defaultOF(T)..

Comment: No, not possible. Bugs me too, used that in C# a lot. This is the way I've come up with that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess I came up with a possible solution. Anyway I must say that Nitzan Tomer is right and the class type is not available in runtime. This is the funny side of TS :)

Here you can check the type of the objects you get in and then set a default value. You could also change the place and the objects to check in order to do it the way you want but I guess it could be a good starting point for you. Notice that you have to do a double cast because TS cannot guarantee that types are compatible. I haven't tried it yet but it compiles well

```
class MyClass<T>{
      myvariable: T 

    constructor(param: any) {
        if (typeof param === 'string') {
            this.myvariable = <T><any> "";
        }
        else if (typeof param === 'number') {
            this.myvariable = <T><any> 0;
        }
    }  
}
```